# Angular Material Table cell not truncating long text

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material's table with Bootstrap's declarative css. Despite setting the width and max width on the table to be 100%, one column does not truncate text properly. This problem typically occurs when the width of the container is not set. What classes should I be applying on Material table to truncate long text.

```
<div class="col flex-grow-1 min-height-0 m-0 p-0">
  <div class="h-100 overflow-auto">
    <table *ngIf="trunks | async as data" mat-table
           [dataSource]="data.entities"
           class="w-100">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
        ... Checkbox logic
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
             ... Header logic, this is much shorter than the offending name
          </ng-container>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let trunk" class="text-truncate">
          <div class="d-inline text-truncate">
            ... Status icon logic, width of < 40px
            <a [routerLink]="['./' + trunk.id]" [queryParams]="{}" queryParamsHandling="merge"
               class="text-truncate">{{ trunk.name }}</a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      ... Other cells with short text
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

`trunk.name` is user entered so it must be truncated eventually.

Stack blitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2menq?file=app/table-basic-example.css

Comment: is it possible to create a stackblitz of this ?

Comment: Working on it, stack blitz is being a pain with unable to find core-js dependency despite it being installed

Comment: Just fork an example from angular material site components examples page, then update with your code

Comment: Added the stack blitz link to the post

Answer (score 15):

I would recommend a pure CSS approach to this particular problem.

```
.truncate-cell {
  max-width: 60px; /* feel free to include any other value */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

And on your component.html, you can simply add the CSS class to that cell.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="truncate-cell"> {{element.name }} </td>
</ng-container>
```

This causes the string within the mat-cell to be contained within a single line, whereby its container has the `overflow` property set as `hidden`.

You may read more about the `text-overflow` property over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

I have also forked a demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2menq-c5byzm?file=app/table-basic-example.css).

Comment: If I want to see the whole context, how can I expand it if I click the cell again in angular? I haven't found a good solution.

Comment: Yes, it's the fastest. If you create a pipe for truncate and suppose you have 500 records then it will slow down the load process.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'truncate'
})

export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: string, args: any[]): string {
        const limit = args.length > 0 ? parseInt(args[0], 10) : 20;
        const trail = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : '...';
        return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="comment">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Comment</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pack" class="truncate-cell"><span>{{pack.comment | truncate:[20, '...']}}</span></td>
            </ng-container>
```